# Convert cell to date in matlab using datenum?

Tags: matlab, date, type-conversion

I have a matrix containing the date in a cell structure. I managed to convert the date (2nd column) using datenum(), but I am not sure how to add on the time (3rd column)

The data looks like this:

```
  'IBM' 20090602    0   108.410000000000
  'IBM' 20090602    500 108.560000000000
```

My code:

```
date = datenum(num2str(IBM(:,2)),'yyyymmdd')
```

Comment: Have you tried `date = datenum(IBM(:,2), 'yyyymmdd')`?

Comment: Yes, I managed to fix it using num2str, but I have another problem now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review your mistakes first:

1. You feed `datenum` with the string `'IBM(:, 2)'` instead of the actual array. Discard the quotes.
2. `datenum` accepts strings, not numerical values.

A possible solution is converting the second column of your data into an array of strings, and feeding it into `datenum`, like so:

```
d = datenum(num2str(vertcat(IBM{:, 2})), 'yyyymmdd');
```

Note that this is, of course, possible **only** if the format of the date string is fixed in each row.

**EDIT:**
To add the values in the third column to the result of `datenum`, simply do the following:

```
d + vertcat(IBM{:, 3})
```

Where `d` is a column vector of date values obtained from `datenum` (I assume that you want to do basic addition, since you haven't specified the actual meaning of the timje values in the third column).

In one line, the complete answer would look like this:

```
datenum(num2str(vertcat(IBM{:, 2})), 'yyyymmdd') + vertcat(IBM{:, 3})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I managed to use num2str for the date column, but it doesn't seem to work for the time column. Is there some way I can add on the time to the datenum?

Comment: Did you follow my solution? It is more than using `num2str`. What is it that doesn't work for you?

Comment: So I tried the following to add the date as part of the input to datenum():

number = cell2mat(IBM(:,2))*100000+cell2mat(IBM(:,3));
date = datenum(num2str(vertcat(number)), 'yyyymmddHHMMSS');
and I get "Failed converting date string to date number"

Comment: Obviously you get this error because you used the format string `yyyymmddHHMMSS` instead of `yyyymmdd`, which basically tells `datenum` to look for the time in the date string as well. However, the input to `datenum` is only date strings (the values from the second column)... where do you expect `datenum` to get the time values from?

Comment: I have revised my answer to add the time values to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can straight-up add the time values in when you're converting to datenum. Just convert from what I assumed were minutes (if they're in seconds, add in another *60 to the divisor) to days, which is what MATLAB uses for its datenum calculations.

```
timestamps = cellfun(@(x,y) datenum(num2str(x),'yyyymmdd')+y/(24*60),...
IBM(:,2),...
IBM(:,3),...
'UniformOutput',false)
```